# I need to merge two lists in Scheme, taking one element from each one

Tags: list, merge, scheme, racket

This is what I've written:

```
(: mmm : (Listof Any) (Listof Any) -> (Listof Any))
(define (mmm list1 list2)
  (cond [(or (null? list1) (null? list2)) null]
        (and (cons (first list1) (first list2)) (mmm (rest list1) (rest list2)))))
```

I'll give you an example:

```
list1:  a b c
list2:  1 2 3
answer: ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

**edited**
they both same size

Comment: By the way, this function is commonly known as `zip`, not `merge`

Comment: Suggest removing 'Scheme' from the tags.  'Typed Racket' is not 'Scheme'

Comment: Are you using Scheme, Racket or Typed Racket as your language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- The base case might or might not be right - if the input lists are guaranteed to be of the same size, then it's fine. If they can be of different size see @Sylwester's answer for advice
- The second condition should start with an `else` (because it's the last one and the conditions are mutually exclusive), not with `and`
- You are not building the output list correctly. The new element to be added is a *list* with the first element of both input lists, and that must be `cons`ed to the result of calling the recursion

To fix them, try this - assuming input lists of equal length:

```
(define (mmm list1 list2)
  (cond [(or (null? list1) (null? list2)) null]
        [else (cons (list (first list1) (first list2))
                    (mmm (rest list1) (rest list2)))]))
```

Now the procedure works as expected:

```
(mmm '(a b c ) '(1 2 3))
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Comment: it look good but the program do me a mistake with the first line      (: mmm : (Listof any) (Listof any) ->(Listof any))

Comment: @user2347210 that's because you're using typed racket. Select "Determine language from source" in the bottom-left corner and make sure that this line is at the beginning of the file: `#lang typed/racket`

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use `map`, you can use:

```
(define (mmm lst1 lst2) (map (lambda (x y) (list x y)) lst1 lst2))
```

Comment: Do you know why `typed/racket` needs `list` wrapped?

Comment: @Sylwester I haven't used `typed/racket`. I don't have an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the lists are the same size, then it becomes simply:

```
(define (mmm list1 list2) (map list list1 list2))
```

Note: Replace `map list` with `map cons` if that is what you really want.  Your code used `cons` but your result example suggests that `list` is what you want.

Comment: I tested this in typed/racket and I get a type error.

Comment: I gave you a Scheme answer.  Typed Racket is not Scheme; please remove the 'Scheme' tag to your question.  That said, `map` has a more general type than `mmm` which is why your type checking is complaining.